# What code is run to manage the file systems in Linux/UNIX?

Tags: linux, unix, filesystems, mount, ext2

For a OS project, I am creating a ext2 file system image and mounting it. This means that I am writing out a 1 MB file with block information and then using it as the mount target.

For example, assume there is a file called `base.img`:

```
fsck.ext2 base.img # checking my file system 
mkdir mnt
sudo mount -o loop base.img mnt
```

After the mount is successful, what is happening internally? From my understanding, my `base.img` simply initializes the image correctly. Internally, these are my questions:

- Is there now a drive partition with this file system?
- How are changes to the file system managed?

For the second, from my understanding, there exists a "mount table" and perhaps an `ext2` module that Linux will use for further changes. Will these changes be reflected in `base.img` or is there a new disk partition for it now?

My underlying question here is: how does this all work?

Comment: You should read a textbook on the design of Linux, it will explain how filesystems work.

Comment: I am reading OSTEP and it barely mentions mount, which is why I ask.

Comment: You could read the source code to the `mount` command.

Comment: Or instead I could ask on a forum, where someone knowledgeable will be able to explain it clearly.

Comment: This site is for answering questions about specific programming problems. Explaining the design of an operating system is too broad.

Comment: My questions are specific: will a disk partition be used or the image file itself for managing updates? is the code that performs these updates kernel internal (modules)?

Comment: I think [linux.se] would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Linux uses block devices to hold data (most of the time those are disks with a partition table at the beginning and multiple partitions, each with a filesystem that then are mounted individually), but any block device will do.

The loop option you are using created a block device (usually in /dev/loop0) and associated it with the file you are using as an image.

For more details see [loop(4)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/loop.4.html)

Answer (score 1):

Ext2 is a block-based filesystem, i.e. it needs a "block device".

A disk is a block device (e.g. `/dev/sda`). A disk partition within a disk is also a block device (e.g. `/dev/sda1`). Linux can also treat memory as block device (`/dev/ram0`).
Essentially anything that can be seen as contiguous bytes that are addressable by offset can be seen as a block device.

And that includes files, like `base.img`, which `mount` will map to block device such as `/dev/loop0`.

Ext2 doesn't care about whether the block device is a disk, a partition, memory, or a file, it just writes things in certain offsets.
(that's a simplification but it's good enough).

So to answer your questions:

> Is there now a drive partition with this file system?

No. There's a new block device (`/dev/loop0`), but not a new partition - partition are a something specific to disks.

> How are changes to the file system managed?
> ...
> how does this all work?

- You write to `mnt`, i.e. "write data A to `/mnt/some/file` at offset X".
- The writes go to ext2.
- ext2 computes what data needs to be written at which block device offset, writes to block device, i.e. "write data B to `/dev/loop0` at offset Y".
- The loopback driver receives this request and forwards them to the filesystem that hosts `base.img` (which may or may not be ext2), i.e. "write data B to `base.img` at offset Y".
- That filesystem does its own computation and creates the request to its own block device, i.e. "write data C to `/dev/sda1` at offset Z".
- The disk driver receives this request and writes to the disk.

> Will these changes be reflected in base.img or is there a new disk partition for it now?

These changes will be reflected in `base.img`, by means of ext2 writing to `/dev/loop0`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I got a bit confused when the loopback driver came in. I tried to take a look [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/net/loopback.c). Why does there need to be multiple writes, once to `/dev/loop0` and once to `/dev/sda1` for `base.img`? Your last line states that its reflected in `base.img` by means of writing to `/dev/loop0`. Where exactly is the connection there?

Comment: A loop device emulates a block device using a file. When you write to the loop device, your write is translated to one or more writes to base.img which is a regular file on disk.